# Return JSON array from database with PHP to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, return

I am trying to return a set of results from PHP to android.

I have been able to return a single results but now I am trying to return multiple ones I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this as an array.

PHP function:

```
   public function searchForPeople($tower) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tower='$tower'") or die(mysql_error());
    $resultNo = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // check for successful store
    if ($result != null) {

        //if just one result return it
        if ($resultNo == 1) {

            // return result
            $resultSet[] = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $resultSet;

    //if more than one loop through
    } else {

        //add each row to an array
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultSet[] = $row;
        }
        return $resultSet;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Section of index.php where i POST my data from android to:

```
    //SEARCH FOR PEOPLE
     else if ($tag == 'searchPeople') {

        $tower = $_POST['tower'];

        $result = $db->searchForPeople($tower);


    // check array has been created
    if ($result != false) {

        $response["success"] = 1;

        $count = 0;
        foreach($result as $row) {

        $response[$count]["user"]["name"] = $row["name"];
        $response[$count]["user"]["email"] = $row["email"];

        $count++;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);


      } else {
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "No users found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    }

        else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
```

I am then trying to get the information back in android as below however recieving the error that there is no value for 0 meaning there must be a problem in the way I have returned the json in PHP.

```
JSONObject results  = new JSONObject(resultsString);
JSONObject json_row = results.getJSONObject("0");
JSONObject json_user = json_row.getJSONObject("user");
```

Im sure this is a problem with returning the PHP array of SQL results. Probably when I am looping through them to add them to either $resultSet or $response.

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
11-14 19:42:37.270: E/JSON(639): "[{\"uid\":\"4\",\"unique_id\":\"505efc638e0f48.78430999\",\"name\":\"fish\",\"email\":\"fish\",\"encrypted_password\":\"r\/Hb7uXrHN8bFuRoKlG8+Y5LdKFjM2QyZDUyYzQ1\",\"salt\":\"c3d2d52c45\",\"created_at\":\"2012-09-23 13:11:15\",\"updated_at\":\"2012-11-03 09:56:15\",\"location\":\"888\",\"tower\":\"IS\",\"base_location\":\"\",\"client_site\":\"\",\"graduate\":\"0\",\"location_updated\":\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\"}]"
11-14 19:42:37.270: E/JSON Parser(639): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"uid":"4","unique_id":"505efc638e0f48.78430999","name":"fish","email":"fish","encrypted_password":"r/Hb7uXrHN8bFuRoKlG8+Y5LdKFjM2QyZDUyYzQ1","salt":"c3d2d52c45","created_at":"2012-09-23 13:11:15","updated_at":"2012-11-03 09:56:15","location":"888","tower":"IS","base_location":"","client_site":"","graduate":"0","location_updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently used a routine similar to the one below. No matter if there is just one result or many results, it always works.

```
$dbuser = // user name;
$dbpass = // password;
$dbhost = // host name;
$dbname = // database name;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE tower=" . $tower;

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$dbh = null;
echo '({"items":'. json_encode($results) .'});';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should dump your `resultsString` to debug `Log` to see how it looks like and whether it is the expected JSON string. Then you can see where, in the server or the client, you must fix the code.

I'd also look into [JSONObject.getJSONArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29), since the response you're sending back consists of nested arrays, AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

To pull the rows in PHP.  Then your result comes ready to be json_encoded into the string you'll need to return to Android.

So try this:

```
function sqlToJSON($sql){
     $sth = mysql_query($sql);

    //if this is an update or an insert nothing to return
    if($sth === false || $sth === true){    

        return null;
    }    

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }   
    return json_encode($rows);
 }
```

You should be able to run the result of this method through `new JSONObject(res);` on the Java side
without having to do any additional translation... I'm saying this from memory, so, it may not be 100% right, but if not, it's pretty close.

Comment: Thanks this does indeed return more than on result however I am getting an JSONerror exception when parsing the returning string in java. Could this be due to my something in the database such as timestamps or blank values?

Comment: hard to say without seeing what your return value actually is.  Can you paste it? Also, what exactly is the Exception you're getting saying? One thing I'm not sure of is whether the entire result is wrapped in { and } as it needs to be, to be well formed JSON.

Comment: Errors posted in EDIT. I have tried various ways now to return this include addslashes and converting to JSONArray instead of JSONObject at the other end but still not luck

Comment: right, as I said, you need to wrap the result in { and }.  Something that starts with [ isn't going to be parsed as JSON.  So, on the java side try `new JSONObject("{" + myPHPResult + "}");`   and see what happens.